# Techniques to estimate biasedness and sampling distribution of b0, b1, and $\sigma$ and confidence/prediction intervals when assumptions are violated?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients, simulation, computational-statistics

This question is for the linear regression model.  Let's say one or more of the assumptions are violated. For example, heteroskedasticity, autocorrelation, or non normality.

I was wondering if there are any references, books, or literature, or if you know how to determine the following:

- Biasedness of b0, b1, and $\sigma$ estimates
- Sampling distribution of b0, b1, and $\sigma$ estimates
- Confidence/prediction intervals

I would imagine a method of simulation could be used.  But I am not sure how.  And let's say you are able to determine the sampling distribution and biasdness of b0 and b1.  How do you translate that to a prediction/confidence interval?

I would like to get to the point where I can build any linear model and answer the questions above.

Thanks!